# Student problem: Amplification of cascade

Tags: transistors

I'm trying to find amplification of this configuration. I'm using small signal analysis but I'm stuck.
I'm new to electronics so please have that in mind.
Here is photo of my problem and my attempt to find solution.
Thanks!

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Do you recognize that Q2 is configured as an emitter-follower (aka common-collector), and do you know what the voltage gain of that configuration is?

Comment: Yes, It has gain of approximately 1, and the Q1 is configured as common emitter which has voltage gain of -gm*Rc. But I want to find gain by definition as Vo/Vi

Comment: @AleksandarSimonović How is that different from the gain of the common emitter stage multiplied by the gain of the emitter follower (1)?

Comment: I know that should be result, but I want to show that analytically using small signal analysis. If u know how to work out equations, please help. Would mean a lot. Thanks

Comment: upvote for a well presented question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not having any fine symbols.

But the solution is trivial. You have written that the 2nd transistor pushes current against its base current (no other way available for AC current). Vbe/(rb)=-G*Vbe

There's 2 possible solutions G=-1/(rb) or Vbe=0. Only the latter is acceptable. Thus the output voltage follows the voltage at the base of the 2nd transistor

Comment: So u want to say that Vpi2 is 0, so output voltage is voltage on resistor Rc. Vo=-gmVpi1*Rc. So the amp should be A=-gmRc* (rpi1/R1+rpi1)

Comment: @AleksandarSimonović yes, that I mean except fix the parenthesis in the expression of A. For homeworks we have here a habit to avoid writing answers that can be copied and pasted as is.

Comment: A=-gm*Rc*(rpi1/(R1+rpi1)) like this?

Comment: @AleksandarSimonović  now it's ok.

Comment: Thanks alot, very helpful